# Change Chromium from automatically launches Nautilus with the Show In Folder command

Tags: chrome, nautilus, fluxbox

Chrome offers a menu for each downloaded item, in which one can `Show in Folder` the item. This menu-command automatically launches Nautilus at the desired location. Nice.

However, now my main desktop management is Fluxbox. So, when Nautilus wakes up, it just replaces my background, and kills all my fluxbox menus, (i am left with an almost empty gtk menus).

In such circumstance, I must use `~$ killall nautilus` to get my fluxdesktop back to normal. This is really funny, but only a dozen of times.

I was wondering if I could parametrize Chromium in some way under linux so as to make Chromium not call Nautilus, but rather call Thunar or PcManFm which are the two file system management I use.

I use Ubuntu 12.04 for info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nautilus seems to be the default application to open a directory,
more precisely to open a file of type `inode/directory`. Furthermore
Nautilus has the bad habit to mess with the desktop as you have
noticed. What you need to do is to tell the system what default
application to use to open a directory and chromium will obey.

In this example I use midnight commander as file manager of choice,
feel free to change it to your preferred one. First you need to
ensure that there's a `.desktop` file which is required by the XDG
specification. For GUI file managers the chance is good that there
already is a suitable `.desktop` file, for terminal applications
usually you have to create your own one. Check out the directory
`/usr/share/applications` for existing files.

Create a file
`~/.local/share/applications/midnight-commander.desktop` with the
following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Midnight Commander
Exec=mc %U
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=false
Type=Application
MimeType=inode/directory
```

The next step is to register this application with the
`inode/directory` MIME type:

```
xdg-mime default midnight-commander.desktop inode/directory
```

You can confirm a successful registration with

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

which should output `midnight-commander.desktop`. Now you can click
on “Open in Folder” in chromium and a terminal should pop up with
midnight commander opened in the directory. No need to even restart
the desktop session or the browser.

If you want to use Nautilus just without having it to mess with your desktop, you need to copy and rename the corresponding `.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications` and replace

```
nautilus %U
```

with

```
nautilus --no-desktop %U
```

Comment: just installed midnight commander because of you... Awsome for the server side, thanx !

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer

Answer (score 4):

You can directly modify `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

Change:

```
inode/directory=nautilus.desktop
```

to:

```
inode/directory=YourFileManager.desktop
```

Eg:

```
inode/directory=pcmanfm.desktop
```