# Cinnamon: lost default nemo launch for shortkey win + E

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, nautilus, nemo

I don't know what changed and I don't know how to set it back,
but now **<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>** launches `baobab` instead of Nemo.

I have check the keyboard - shortcuts configurations.
and Launchers/Home Folder is associated to **<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>**.

There is no custom shortcuts.

So my issues are of 2 types:

- the shortcut configuration seems correct in cinnamon panel,
- still it launches the wrong application(baobab), which doesn't appear in said configuration.

What can I check and correct to get back default behavior: **<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>** => Home folder?

A package name to reinstall the default bindings would be ok as well.

EDIT:
when downloading with Firefox, *"show in folder"* menu trigger nemo,
but When downloading with chrome, *"show in folder"* trigger baoab.

So chrome seem to use the same information as cinnamon to launch nemo,
but which one ?

PS: 
So far I didn't found any answer that solve this specific issue (including on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/).

`lsb_release -a` ouputs

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 18 Sarah
Release:    18
Codename:   sarah
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the issue in /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache, with the following entry:

```
inode/directory=org.gnome.baobab.desktop;nemo.desktop;
```

changing it back to:

```
inode/directory=nemo.desktop;
```

solved the issue.

It's the chrome behavior and the answer to [Change Chromium from automatically launches Nautilus with the Show In Folder command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57302/change-chromium-from-automatically-launches-nautilus-with-the-show-in-folder-com) that get me to the solution.

EDIT: `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` is regenerated from `.desktop` files present in folder `/usr/share/applications/`. Initial error is  in org.gnome.baobab.desktop and reappear each time mimeinfo.cache is regenereated. It is not clear how to fix this.

Comment: How often is the mimeinfo.cache regenerated?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that `cat /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache | grep baobab` yields
`inode/directory=nemo.desktop;org.gnome.baobab.desktop;`

However, I don't have chrome - does chromium count?
Anyway Super+E => Home folder (nemo) is still working.

On a fairly clean system, I have two baobab.desktop files:-

```
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/baobab:org.gnome.baobab.desktop
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.baobab.desktop
```